# Java Annotation compilation error "Incompatible type found"

Tags: java, compilation, annotations

I am facing a weird error while compiling one of the annotation its throwing compilation error like

```
[javac] /src/main/java/com/FilterResult.java:29: incompatible types  
[javac] found   : com.FilterResult.Mode  
[javac] required: com.FilterResult.Mode  
[javac]Mode value() default Mode.ENABLE;
```

My source code contents are given below:

```
package com;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Documented

@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface FilterResult
{
   public enum Mode { ENABLE, DISABLE };

   Mode value() default Mode.ENABLE;
}
```

Can somebody please help me resolving this?

The JDK version that is used is 1.6U27 and also this error occurs only when I compile with ant. Direct jdk compilation goes through.

Comment: Do you have other (older?) classes somewhere on your classpath during Ant compilation?

Comment: No .. initialy even i thought so and cleaned all the class files. also surprisingly the compilation goes through if i point the java home to jdk 1.7.but unfortunately i have to use 1.6 only